# svg, canvas together without using position absolute

Tags: css, canvas, svg, d3.js

I am trying to make both svg and canvas in same container for generating charts. 
In that SVG is used to draw axis,gridlines, where events added on this svg element.
Then canvas is used to draw the chart ,may be bar or line.
The condition here is i dont want to use position:absolute property to both svg and canvas.Because i want canvas to be rendererd above svg and events should be trigged on svg.

Answer (score -1):

Try `position:absolute` and `pointer-events:none` on the canvas element.

Comment: You have a good answer, but...chuckle...the title of the question states "without using position absolute".

Comment: Yeah, but I'm reading between the lines ;-).  The text does not give any reason why to avoid `position:absolute`.

Comment: Agreed...I like your answer, just the irony of it! :)

Comment: But position:absolute and pointer-events:none is not working in IE9 @ThomasW

Comment: If I add position:absolute to svg element, my gridline drawn over the bar chart. If I add position:absolute to canvas element , events was not triggered on SVG. However your comment position:absolute and pointer-events:none helped me for firefox, chrome.However it fails in IE9. In IE9, if i gave position:absolute and pointer-events:none to canvas element, event was not triggering @ThomasW

Comment: You're right, IE only supports `pointer-events` for SVG. If you put the `<canvas>` inside a `<foreignObject>` element and apply `pointer-events:none` to the `<foreignObject>`, it should work. But that's maybe a bit over-complicated. Why do you want to mix SVG and canvas in the first place? What can canvas do for your charts that SVG can't do?